# How to access inbuilt functions?

Tags: matlab, function

As what should I be typing in the Command Window to get the function file to open?

Usually I get a link to them when debugging and an error occurs, but what command can be used to access them directly?

Comment: That is more like the explanation of the function. I wanted the actual codes of the function. Say I want to see the size function codes, what should I type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`edit functionName`, e.g. `edit repmat`.

There are built-in functions that are not written in Matlab, but for these functions you cannot take a look at the code even if an error occurs.

Comment: Ok, I guess that is because it is closed source?
So the size function is already built into the program and is not in a function file?
Is there a reason why some of the functions can be edited?

Comment: @Greatporedout You pretty much answered it yourself - some functions are built-in to the Matlab environment, and some are just m files which you can view the source code for.

Comment: @jazzbassrob is there a reason behind not building all functions into the environment? I guess this question is not exactly related to my main question, but kind of interested to know why.

Comment: Sometimes it might be for speed, but it may also because it performs some low-level function which can't be done in an m file - for example, `size`.  How would you write an m file script which gets the dimensions of an array without using the `size` function?  This has to be built-in because it is a fundamental operation which is part of the Matlab environment.